# Create Service Provider with Oauth2 with SOAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to create a SP via SOAP. The call for creating a SP is correct after which I try to configure Oauth2 via SOAP specifying oauthConsumerKey and oauthConsumerSecret like so

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.oauth.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:registerOAuthApplicationData>
         <xsd:application>
            <xsd1:OAuthVersion>OAuth-2.0</xsd1:OAuthVersion>
            <xsd1:applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</xsd1:applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>
            <xsd1:applicationName>test</xsd1:applicationName>
            <xsd1:callbackUrl>regexp=(.*)/login/oauth2/code/wso2</xsd1:callbackUrl>
            <xsd1:grantTypes>refresh_token urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer implicit password client_credentials iwa:ntlm authorization_code urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer</xsd1:grantTypes>
            <xsd1:oauthConsumerKey>gVWBVK0pdX4pg2Yk3fFbBjKe1aUa</xsd1:oauthConsumerKey>
            <xsd1:oauthConsumerSecret>CbfGJXhTYvb3i1BAfu5ijgUSXXYa</xsd1:oauthConsumerSecret>
            <xsd1:pkceMandatory>false</xsd1:pkceMandatory>
            <xsd1:pkceSupportPlain>true</xsd1:pkceSupportPlain>
            <xsd1:refreshTokenExpiryTime>86400</xsd1:refreshTokenExpiryTime>
            <xsd1:userAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</xsd1:userAccessTokenExpiryTime>
         </xsd:application>
      </xsd:registerOAuthApplicationData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but in db I found different keys, oauth version, callbackUrl and grant_types as in screen attached
[image: DB screen]
Am I doing something wrong?

when i run the SOAP the response is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:registerOAuthConsumerResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ax2408="http://dto.oauth.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2404="http://oauth.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2405="http://base.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd"><ns:return>BE2JqA9lOZQKSkMvo4diNy2QHb0a</ns:return><ns:return>7xjxUrbWOztADfODEcvEbn8NeuEa</ns:return></ns:registerOAuthConsumerResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version and the database type that you are using for IS?

Comment: I'm using wso2 is 5.10 and postgres db

Comment: Hope you missed <soapenv:Envelope> starting tag when copy-pasting. Other than that this SOAP request body is correct. I tried the exact same request body and it works fine. I think you are looking at a different entry in the table. Can you refresh the idn_oauth_consumer_apps table and see the entries after the SOAP call

Comment: I've update the answare... it dosn't work for me

Comment: @Jalisse The given SOAP Response is not the expected response for the mentioned SOAP request(registerOAuthApplicationData). For the mentioned soap request you should get a registerOAuthApplicationDataResponse. If you execute registerOAuthConsumer SOAP request only you get a registerOAuthConsumerResponse. The database entry you are looking at is generated due to a registerOAuthConsumer request. Seems you are using a different soap request

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/service-provider-configurations-used-with-apis/#sample-request-and-response_1

Comment: true, I missed the calls!!  thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the answer from the comments:

1. The mentioned SOAP request is the 'registerOAuthApplicationData' request in  https://localhost:9443/services/OAuthAdminService. The expected response should be similar to the sample response given in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/service-provider-configurations-used-with-apis/#sample-request-and-response_1 (registerOAuthApplicationDataResponse)
   If a 'registerOAuthApplicationData' SOAP request is made "idn_oauth_consumer_apps" table entry should be populated with the given details (ie: provided client key, secret, callback etc)
2. The mentioned SOAP response in the question is expected for the 'registerOAuthConsumer' request in https://localhost:9443/services/OAuthAdminService. It generates an OAuth consumer with randomly generated client key and secret and other default values. Such entry is reflected in your attached image.

That means you have executed an incorrect SOAP request.